# Python Split Strings While Preserving Order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

I have a list of strings in python, where I need to preserve order and split some strings.

The condition to split a string is that after first match of `:` there is a none space/new line/tab char.

For example, this must be split:

`example: Test` to `['example':, 'Test']`

While this stays the same: `example:`         , `IGNORE_ME_EXAMPLE`

---

Given an input like this:
`['example: Test', 'example:         ', 'IGNORE_ME_EXAMPLE']`

I'm expecting:
`['example:', 'Test', 'example:         ', 'IGNORE_ME_EXAMPLE']`

Please Note that split strings are yet stick to each other and follow original order.

Plus, whenever I split a string I don't want to check split parts again. In other words, I don't want to check `'Test'` after I split it.

To make it more clear, Given an input like this:

`['example: Test::YES']`

I'm expecting:
`['example:', 'Test::YES']`

Comment: please review [ask]. you're expected to make an attempt. all I see here is someone outsourcing a few minutes of programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loop comprehension for the input list:

```
l = ['example: Test::YES']

l1 = [j.lower().strip() for i in l for j in i.split(":", 1) if j.strip().lower() != '']
print(l1)
```

**Output:**

```
['example', 'Test::YES']
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I want. Please note the condition to split..

Comment: @robert Yes, I have just noticed. Please wait while I edit the answer.

Comment: I think this solves all, but can we make it more efficient? I'm calling some functions multiple time `l1 = [j.strip().lower() for i in l for j in i.split(":", 1) if j.strip().lower() != '']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for that:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(.+:)\s+([^\s].+)")

result = []
for line in lines:
    match = pattern.match(line)
    if match:
        result.append(match.group(1))
        result.append(match.group(2))
    else:
        result.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate over your list of words, for each word, you need to check if `:` present or not. if present the then split the word in 2 parts, pre `:` and post part. append these pre and post to final list and if there is no `:` in word add that word in the result list and skip other operation for that word

```
# your code goes here
wordlist = ['example:', 'Test', 'example:         ', 'IGNORE_ME_EXAMPLE']
result = []
for word in wordlist:
    index = -1
    part1, part2 = None, None
    if ':' in word:
        index = word.index(':')
    else:
        result.append(word)
        continue

    part1, part2 = word[:index+1], word[index+1:]
    if part1 is not None and len(part1)>0:
        result.append(part1)
    if part2 is not None and len(part2)>0:
        result.append(part2)
    
print(result)
```

output

```
['example:', 'Test', 'example:', '         ', 'IGNORE_ME_EXAMPLE']
```